# Find the solutions of $3\{x\} = 2x + [x]$ where $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part and $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the solutions of $3\{x\} = 2x + [x]$ where $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part and $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

I tried to approach the problem as follows:

$3\{x\} = 3[x] + 2 \{x\}$   (as $x = [x] + \{x\}$)

$\{x\}=3[x]$

now we know that LHS belongs to $0$ to $1$ ($0$ included $1$ excluded)
hence $3[x]$ belongs to $[0,1)$
hence $[x]$ belongs to $[0,1/3)$
therefore $[x] = 0$
and hence $x$ belongs to $[0,1)$
but at $x=0.5$ and in fact, all the values except $0$ don't satisfy the given equation.
why is this contradiction arising?

Comment: Is it  $2x$ or $2\{x\}$ in the right hand side?

Comment: You reached $\lfloor x\rfloor = 0$, and still have to figure out the factional part of $x$ by $\{x\} = 3\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then reject $x=0.5$ and other non-zero $x$.

Comment: it is 2x in RHS

Answer (score 1):

$$3\{x\} = 3[x] + 2 \{x\}\\\Rightarrow\{x\}=3[x]\\\Rightarrow[x]+\{x\}=4[x]\\\Rightarrow x=4[x]$$

There is no other number than $0$ which is four times of it's greatest integer value. Therefore, $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $x= a+b$ where a is integer and b is rational part, $0\le b<1$

$$3b = 2a + 2b + a$$
$$b = 3a$$

But b is between 0 and 1. So:

$$0\le 3a < 1$$
$$0\le a < \frac{1}{3}$$

$a$ was integer. Only one integer satisfies the inequality is 0. If $a=0$, it follows $b=0$ and $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$3\{x\}=2x+[x]$, let $x=n+q, n\in I, 0\le q<1$.
Then $3q=2n+2q+n \implies 0\le  3n=q < 1 \implies n=0, q=0$.
$x=0+0=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathrm{3}\left\{{x}\right\}=\mathrm{2}{x}+\left[{x}\right] \\ $$
$$\mathrm{3}\left\{{x}\right\}=\mathrm{2}\left(\left\{{x}\right\}+\left[{x}\right]\right)+\left[{x}\right] \\ $$
$$\mathrm{3}\left[{x}\right]=\left\{{x}\right\}\Rightarrow\left[{x}\right]=\mathrm{0} \\ $$
$$\mathrm{3}\left({x}−\left[{x}\right]\right)=\mathrm{2}{x}+\left[{x}\right] \\ $$
$${x}=\mathrm{5}\left[{x}\right]=\mathrm{0} \\ $$